# beginResetModel () and endResetModel () doesn’t work when data contained in QStringListModel changed

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

beginResetModel () and endResetModel () doesn’t work when data contained in QStringListModel changed in my code here ,anyone can explain why ?

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *



class BoxLayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.view = QTableView()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.lst=[]
        self.stringListModel=QStringListModel (self.lst)
        self.view.setModel(self.stringListModel)

        self.timer = QTimer(self);
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerHit)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def timerHit(self):
        self.stringListModel.beginResetModel ()
        self.lst.append(QTime.currentTime().toString())
        print(self.lst)
        self.stringListModel.endResetModel ()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = BoxLayout()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: try `self.stringListModel.setStringList(self.lst)`. I assume the model to copy the python list and convert it to QStringList, so updating `lst` won't automatically update the model.

Comment: yes ,it worked .but I cannot agree with you ,you could test the following code to dig,it worked !!!http://codepad.org/TnwEzpTH

Comment: The code you mention works. But only because it overrides the `data` and `rowCount` methods of the custom StringModel.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/34158/